# Queue resolves in iphone processor overdrive

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to combine a queue with Core Data. Upon executing the function the processor goes up to 99% and stays there. If I do not use a queue the processor does not go in overdrive and returns to 1%. Why? What is wrong with the queue?

```
      func addGalleryPhotoToCoreDataFromImage(image: UIImage) 
  {
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) { () -> Void in
        // create a thumbnail and a smaller photo

        let thumbnailImage = self.resizeImage(image, targetSize: CGSizeMake(167, 167))
       let screenSize : CGSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
       let bigImage = self.resizeImage(image, targetSize: CGSizeMake(screenSize.width, screenSize.height))

        // save thumbnail and photo to CoreData
       let newPhoto = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Photo", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as! Photo
       newPhoto.thumbnail = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbnailImage, 0.1)
       newPhoto.photo = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(bigImage, 0.9)
       self.photoSet!.addObject(newPhoto)
        self.saveToCoreData()
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
           self.refreshItemsInGalleryCollectionView()
        })
      }
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean with *If I do not use a queue*? Do you mean that everything works as expected when you do all the logic simply without a queue?

Comment: With the queue everything works as supposed to. Without the queue everything works as supposed to. But when I use a queue the processor hits 99% and stays at 99%. I used the queue because transforming an image is expensive and I do not want the UI to lag.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code that saves to coredata inside the main queue

Comment: Isn't saving to Core Data a process that could cause a lag too?

Comment: I totally agree that the image conversion will cause a greater lag. But why can't the saving to Core Data be done in a queue?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10754466)

Comment: Can someone please explain me in which cases a second managedObjectContext is needed with the performBlock: method? For it seems I could save to CoreData that way in the global-queue.

Comment: @AlexJolig This solves the problem he was having, thus it answers the question. Please explain why you think this does not provide answer!